# Aligning text to right of image withing <li>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having an issue with this and I know its something simple I am doing wrong but I dont have the time to keep playing around with it till I figure it out. I have here two ul's and in each of the li's I need the text to align to the right of the images and not wrap underneath like it is [EXAMPLE IMAGE OF ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebVtr.jpg)

```
<section id="providerBenefits">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h1 class="display-3">Befefits<br />for providers</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul id="benefitListLeft">
          <li><img src="./assets/img/CCM-Page_12.png" />Lower costs and higher revenue</li>
          <li><img src="./assets/img/CCM-Page_16.png" />Valued-based chronic care management with full system setup</li>
          <li><img src="./assets/img/CCM-Page_23.png" />Coordination of total care plan of<br />20-minute clinical staff time</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul id="benefitListRight">
          <li><img src="./assets/img/CCM-Page_09.png" />80-85% comprehensive care plan<br />established, implemented, and monitored</li>
          <li><img src="./assets/img/CCM-Page_18.png" />Electronic Health Record system<br />compatibility</li>
          <li><img src="./assets/img/CCM-Page_21.png" />24/7 acces to statistical reports</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post your css and make a snippet.

Comment: Only CSS I have is a list style: none on the ul. Everything I have tried has failed me.

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: ok. please try using this  `ul li img{ float: left; padding: 10px; }`

Comment: I can't believe that none of the suggestions that pop up when you are typing the question have the answer.

Comment: This is simple as it can be done using flexbox. Also a better approach in responsive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer for it you can have a look in the provided [example](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/91t0sevb/)

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/91t0sevb/'
```

You can also do it by using flex box. here is the code and [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/91t0sevb/1/)

```
<section id="providerBenefits">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="benefitListRight">
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/ffffff/000000" /><span>80-85% comprehensive care plan<br />established, implemented, and monitored</span></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/ffffff/000000" /><span>80-85% comprehensive care plan<br />established, implemented, and monitored</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Css

```
ul
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
ul li {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li img {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please share your solution in the answer itself: there is a reason why we don't allow posting of links without any accompanying code.

Comment: This is my account and i have made my own changes there not a copy paste.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it is your account or not. If you're going to post just a link as an answer without bothering to invest a minimal amount of effort to explain your solution, post it as a comment instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter a good coder can better understand whether it is mentioned in a link or here.

Comment: @Anmol Sandal , We are not solving problem for a particular person/op, Its possible that in future someone get same problem. then he came here and find the link broken or not active.. That's why "we don't allow posting of links without any accompanying code." Hope you understand.

Comment: Agree, I didn't thought about the broken link. :-)

Comment: This helped I was able to figure it out from there, Thank you

Comment: Thanks @soundevour

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method instead of ul li element..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="...">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
            Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/PjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNjQiIGhlaWdodD0iNjQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NCA2NCIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+PGRlZnMvPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI2NCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI2NCIgZmlsbD0iI0VFRUVFRSIvPjxnPjx0ZXh0IHg9IjEzLjQ2MDkzNzUiIHk9IjMyIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojQUFBQUFBO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgT3BlbiBTYW5zLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmLCBtb25vc3BhY2U7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEwcHQ7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+NjR4NjQ8L3RleHQ+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="...">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
            Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose `img` in a `span` and this `span` and `text` in a `div` with `dispal:flex;`

i.e, `li` will be changed to

```
 <li>
    <div>
        <span><img src="https://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>
        Lower costs and higher revenue
    </div>
 </li>
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="providerBenefits">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h1 class="display-3">Befefits<br />for providers</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul id="benefitListLeft">
          <li><div>
          <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>Lower costs and higher revenue
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
          <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>Valued-based chronic care management with full system setup
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
          <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>Coordination of total care plan of<br />20-minute clinical staff time
          </div></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul id="benefitListRight">
          <li><div>
          <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>80-85% comprehensive care plan<br />established, implemented, and monitored
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
          <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>Electronic Health Record system<br />compatibility
          </div></li>
          <li><div>
          <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" /></span>24/7 acces to statistical reports
          </div></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```